# How to get rid of pdf dead white space in React for react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

Currently I created a pdf display through the use of react-pdf, however I am facing one problem with dead white space. Currently, the pdf gets added a huge amount of white space beneath for some reason and I don't know what the possible fix could be after playing around with the styles:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";
import { pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
import "react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css";

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js",
  import.meta.url
).toString();

const ResumeDisplay = () => {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(1);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const styles = {
    container: {
      maxWidth: "900px",
      margin: "auto",
    },
  };

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  const onFileChange = (url) => {
    setFile(url);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onFileChange(
      "https://mypdf.pdf"
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      {file && (
        <Document file={file} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
          <Page pageNumber={1} style={styles.page} scale={1.5} />
        </Document>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResumeDisplay;
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problems and as I inspect the element, I found out the white space is react-pdf text layer - in this case, you just need to set it to false. Another reason is because the PDF file is so large - some pages will be blank and you will need to wait.

```js
<Page
  pageNumber={1} 
  style={styles.page} 
  scale={1.5}               
  renderAnnotationLayer={false} 
  renderTextLayer={false}
/>
```

In case that the pdf file is so large, I find out that we can customize the loading effect (default is "Loading PDF...") - I tried but it's not working very well for me...

```js
<Document file={file} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} loading={/*string or react component here*/}>
  <Page pageNumber={1} style={styles.page} scale={1.5} loading={/*string or react component here*/}/>
</Document>
```

Finally, you can use [this](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-pdf/test/) to test your PDF file with `react-pdf`.